# How can I tell the difference between a regular object and a jquery object (page element)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, element, typeof

```
// var = {hey: "baby"};
// or 
// var = $('#thingy');

if(typeof var == 'object'){  // this is true for both =(
}
```

I need my code to be smart enough to be able to tell the difference between these two. What's the best way to accomplish that?

Comment: @jeremy That question is about distinguishing DOM elements, this question is about jQuery objects.

Comment: i suppose i could use the answer from the other question and just turn my jquery object into a dom elmement using $('#thingy')[0] ...

Comment: quack quack: ob.nodeType says the html element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the instanceof operator for this.

```
obj instanceof jQuery
```

In addition, I don't think you want to use "var" as a variable name. It's reserved to establish variable scope.